# Getting text from EditText gives question marks

Tags: android, android-edittext

Just take a look at this:
[image: edittext question marks android]

I'm getting text with `editText.getText().toString()`. Replacing � doesn't help.

Dave here's a piece of code for you, I don't know what else I can put here.

```
final EditText login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1)
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                if (login.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, textBad, duration).show();
                } else {
                    button.setEnabled(false);
                    Toast.makeText(context, textGood, duration).show();
                    apiKey = login.getText().toString();
                    try {
                        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME,
                                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        fos.write(apiKey.getBytes());
                        fos.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.v("EditText", login.getText().toString());
                    String zz = login.getText().toString().replace(" ", "")
                            .replace("�", "");
                    String[] dupcia = new String[] { zz };
                    new RetreiveFeedTask().execute(dupcia); 
                    Log.e("heja", ":)");

            }

        }

    });
```

Comment: Please give some code

Comment: @David edited, I think that's all I should give.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `regex expr`

```
str.replaceAll("[^\\p{Alpha}\\p{Digit}]+","")
```

Answer (score 0):

That character indicates that you have a problem with your character encoding.

From the [Specials (Unicode block) Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_%28Unicode_block%29):

> U+FFFD �: replacement character used to replace an unknown or unrepresentable character

Without knowing more about your application, it is difficult to pinpoint your specific problem. If you are setting the text of this EditText, make sure that you are using the same character encoding everywhere. If this text is being set by the user, I'm curious as to how you are getting non-unicode characters from the keyboard.